# PostgreSQL: how to resolve "numeric field overflow" problem

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following schema

> COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION,...., NUMERIC_PRECISION_INTEGER
>     "year";1;"";"YES";"numeric";;;17;10;17
>   "month_num";2;"";"YES";"numeric";;;17;10;17
>   "month_name";3;"";"YES";"text";;1073741824;;;
>   "week_of_month";4;"";"YES";"numeric";;;17;10;17
>   "count_of_contracts";5;"";"YES";"bigint";;;64;2;0

but when I insert the following into it

```
insert into contract_fact values(2011, 8, 'Aug', 1, 367)
```

I see the following error

> ERROR: numeric field overflow
>    SQL state: 22003
>    Detail: A field with precision 17, scale 17 must round to an absolute value less than 1.

Comment: This not a schema but a dump from some internal postgres table. If you could have the courtesy to produce something readable, like the output from \d <tablename> or the CREATE TABLE statement that was used to create this table (pgAdmin3 can help you with this)? Also, a field declared numeric(X,Y) can use up to X places, with Y decimals right to the comma. Which means that if X=Y you can only store values < 1.

Comment: Also, please include the column list in your INSERTs, depending on any particular column order is a bad idea.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It looks like you have your `year` and `week_of_month` columns defined as `numeric(17,17)`, which means 17 digits, 17 of which are behind the decimal point.  So the value has to be between 0 and 1.  You probably meant `numeric(17,0)`, or perhaps you should use an integer type.

Comment: i know that you are correct, but i honestly can't understand. how constraint of 17 digits before and 17 digits behind the decimal point leads to [0,1] possible value range?

Comment: for those who got confused a little bit as i did. precision - number of digits totally; scale - number of decimal places. If you get `number(17, 17`) - you say: number will store 17 digits as a whole AND reserve 17 digits for decimal points. Leaving with range [0, 1].

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem even without having set an upper limit.
If this happens to you, you might want to look at the global PostgreSQL limits here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html

For instance TIMESTAMP are a kind of BIGINT with a limit of `9223372036854775807` so you might want to validate that the integer your are passing in your query is below that value.